# connect html with spring mvc controller

Tags: spring

I have a class which send an email with activation link and the message is something like that :

```
String message =  "<html> <body><a href=\"http://localhost:8080/token?foo=abc\" >ACTIVE MY ACCOUNT</a> </body></html>";
```

On the other hand I have a controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/token",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class RegisterController {
    public String active(@RequestParam("foo") String foo) {
       return foo;
   }
}
```

and I want foo to have abc value, but now when I click on activation link I got

Problem accessing /token.

Reason:
Not Found

How can I modify this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative :

You access a resource with the url (your variable is in the uri)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/token")
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{foo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String active(@PathVariable String foo) {
       return foo;
   }
}
```

And

```
String message =  "<html> <body><a href=\"http://blockedcontent:8080/token/abc\" >ACTIVE MY ACCOUNT</a> </body></html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in that way

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegisterController {

@RequestMapping(value="/token", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String active(
    @RequestParam("token") String token) {
    return token;

 }

}
```

and

```
String url =  "<html> <body><a href=\"http://localhost:8080/register/token?token=abc\" >ACTIVE MY ACCOUNT</a> </body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing WebContentPath in the href link, which is Project Name if you didn't change it. So the href should be `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/token?foo=abc`

By the way, the href should not be hard coded.

Comment: I have others controllers which works with something like that http://localhost:8080/something and I don't have to put project name